# how to enter a new data in static text gui matlab without clearing previous data in it

Tags: matlab, user-interface

I'm new in gui matlab.I created a gui. In it, I do some calculation with push button named process and the result is showed in static text named `texthistory`. Each time , I do a new calculation, the new result is showed in texthistory and the previous data is deleted. But I want  both of them to be showed in texthistory. 
How can I do that?

Thank you.
Here's my code:

```
function processpb_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to processpb (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
if isempty(handles.D)
    warndlg('Please Insert Image','Warning');
elseif handles.flag(1)~=0 ;

else
    Val            =  get(handles.psf1,'String');

    Bw             =  im2bw(handles.D);
    s              =  regionprops(Bw, handles.D, 'Centroid');
    sx1            =  round(s.Centroid(1));
    sy1            =  round(s.Centroid(2));

    roi2           =  handles.roi/2;

    i              =  (sx1-((roi2)-1)):(sx1+ roi2);
    j              =  (sy1-((roi2)-1)):(sy1+ roi2);
    ROI            =  (handles.D(i,j));
    ROI            =  (2^16-1)-ROI;
    handles.avg1   =  (sum(ROI(:)/str2num(Val))./((handles.roi).^2));


end   
a1=['Reference ROI pixel value at 100 MU:  ',num2str(handles.avg)];
a2=['Image ROI pixel value at 100 MU:  ',num2str(handles.avg1)];
clock=[num2str(date), ' --- ',num2str(handles.c(4)),': ',num2str(handles.c(5))]; 
popval1=get(handles.popupmenu1,'Value');
strval1=get(handles.popupmenu1,'String');
type1=strval1{popval1};

popval2=get(handles.popupmenu2,'Value');
strval2=get(handles.popupmenu2,'String');
type2=strval2{popval2};
A={clock ,type1,type2, a1,a2}';

 set(handles.texthistory,'String',A)


guidata(hObject,handles);
```

Comment: Do you want just the last two values? Or all the previous values as well?

Comment: I want all the previous values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this

```
previous_text = get(handles.texthistory,'String');
new_text = sprintf('%s\n%s',previous_text,A);
set(handles.texthistory,'String', new_text);
```

Comment: Thank you but i got this error: Error using sprintf
Function is not defined for 'cell' inputs.

Comment: A needs to be a string, it is a cell in this case. For example this should work, but the format won't be nice: `A=[clock type1 type2 a1 a2]`. This page should be useful for you: https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/formatting-strings.html

Comment: Thanks for your help